# Profile Preferences --> Q&A Emails is... broken

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, email, preferences

I cannot seem to remove this email address.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Remove email address
2. Hit "Save email settings"
3. See the error (even though both checkboxes are unchecked)

[image]

I'm also not sure how to get rid of this either, since to do so requires a notification email confirmation:

[image]

---

A related error is that when I change my profile email address, it does not propagate to this field. I was unaware I had another email address to change here.

My suggestion would be (or bug report, not sure intended functionality) that:

1. You can submit a blank email address for Preferences
2. When changing your "Edit Profile" email address, somehow notify the user there is another email address OR automatically change it (or just get rid of the second email address field...)

Comment: Also my gravatar randomly vanished and I cannot find it! plz help urgently to find my happy face. 

Comment: Gravatars are based on email hashes... a different email means a different gravatar.

Comment: @enderland Gravatar is based off of the email set on your profile (rather than notification preferences). If you remove that address, you lose the gravatar. One workaround is to just upload your chosen gravatar.